# Laravel with MySQL and Redis, best approach to use - filtering items with hasMany()

Tags: mysql, laravel, optimization, redis, eloquent

I'm working on an app and would like to use the Redis for the first time to make part of the queries faster. Just to be sure, I would like to keep my MySQL in the background as a fallback and to keep data related in a way it's familiar to me.

Let me describe the scenario I have:

I have three models: `category`, `subcategory` and `events`.

`events` columns are: `id`,`subcategory_id`,`occurs_at`,`parameter_`,`parameter_2`, ...

`events` belong to the `subcategory` and `subcategory` belongs to the `category`. These are one to many relations.

My idea was following:

Whenever the `events` instance is created I create the Redis [hash entry](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) (forgive me my syntax as it was some time that I studied Redis):

`event:{event_id} category 4 subcategory 25 at "occurs_at" parameter_1 12 paremeter_2 55`

Now that I have these in Redis I would like to do the following queries:

- go through all events and get unique category_id's -> go back to MySQL and fetch the information of these categories (as description and such) using Eloquent
- go through all events and get filtered (using [MATCH](http://redis.io/commands/scan)) category_id's, for example where parameter_1 larger than 245 -> and again go back to MySQL and fetch the information of these categories (as description and such) using Eloquent

First question is: is this a good approach? I would like to have all the data in my MySQL db just in case but still utilize the Redis to familiarize myself with it and make the queries faster.

Second idea: Should I use Eloquent to fetch the `category` instance after I got the proper ones from the Redis or should I save all of the data in the Redis hash as:

`event:{event_id} category 4 subcategory 25 at "occurs_at" parameter_1 12 paremeter_2 55 category_parameter_1 "some data from category model" category_parameter_2 "some other data from category model"`

Third idea: make another set of hashes for categor and fetch them instead of the data from the eloquent.

`category:{category_id} category_parameter_1 "some data" category_parameter_2 "more data"`

Any thoughts, pointers, links to similar tutorial are more than welcome. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Example Eloquent query:

In `category` model:

```
public function events()
{
  return $this->hasManyThrough('Event', 'Subcategory');
}
```

Then a query would be:

```
$categories = Category::whereHas('events', function ($query) {
    $query->where('occurs_at', '>=', Carbon::today());
})->get();
```

Hope I didn't miss something..

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a sample SQL query and explain why it needs to be faster.

Comment: @ArminSam I want to advance my skills and learn Redis. I'll add the example query in the code, give me a second.